# How to compare strings?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro in Outlook which passes an argument to a macro in Excel.

An If statement is not correctly comparing two values.

I also tried `Like` and `InStr()`.

```vb
Sub increase(gageID As String)
Dim temp As String
'MsgBox gageID  Shows correct string
Set Rng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each cell In Rng
    temp = cell.Value
    'MsgBox temp  Loops through every cell in column A correctly
    If temp = gageID Then 'Can't compare for some reason
        MsgBox cell.Value    'Code never reaches here, no errors thrown
        MsgBox "test3"
        cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = cell.Offset(0, 9).Value + 7       
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error? Have you tried `Debug.Print` to see what the values are?

Comment: As I mentioned, no errors were thrown during the execution. Debug.Print shows nothing

Comment: Put a breakpoint or stepthrough code to where you compare `If temp = gageID` and either in your code or in the immediate window run `Debug.print temp` and `Debug.print gageID`.  If there are no errors it would seem pretty clear that its just not matching a value.

Comment: Debug.print your rng.address and fully qualify your range, meaning include a worksheet object. Furthermore put these variables into the watches window and keep an eye out on them when you step through your code

Comment: @MichaelDjurdjevic Can you show us an example of how you're calling `increase()`? Your code worked fine for me.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Z32HJdx.png please see attached photo, why would bool be false in this case? I also tried ```If temp Like gageID``` with no success

Comment: Seems like leadin/trailing spaces, use Trim

Comment: Because they are not the same.  One has a leading space, one doesn't.

Comment: Do you see that " " space in the gageID value? The strings must match exactly.  You can wrap them in `trim` to remove extra spaces on the outside. `If trim(temp) = trim(gageID)`

Answer (score 0):

*You could do [Trim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions) and use **[StrComp function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/strcomp-function)***

> Returns a Variant (String) containing a copy of a specified string without leading spaces (LTrim), trailing spaces (RTrim), or both leading and trailing spaces (Trim).

---

> A comparison of two sequences of characters. Use Option Compare to specify binary or text comparison. In English-U.S., binary comparisons are case sensitive; text comparisons are not.